# Performing two methods inside a dataframe without overwriting to find Chinese characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I want to recognise all the Chinese characters. However, I have several columns that could contain Chinese characters.
If I now run the methods one after the other, it understandably overwrites the other method.

How could I run both methods with the consideration that it overwrites the other one only if there is a 0? So that in the end I have found all the Chinese characters.

Dataframe

```py
    id  name        secondName
0   1   Max Power   约翰·多伊
1   2   Jessica     Miller
2   3   约翰·多伊   哈拉尔
3   4   哈拉尔量杯   Johnny
4   5   Frank       High
```

Code

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'name': ['Max Power', 'Jessica', '约翰·多伊', '哈拉尔量杯', 'Frank'],
     'secondName': ['约翰·多伊', 'Miller', '哈拉尔', 'Johnny', 'High'],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df)
df['chinese'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: 1 if len(re.findall(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', x)) > 0 else 0)
df['chinese'] = df['secondName'].apply(lambda x: 1 if len(re.findall(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', x)) > 0 else 0)
display(df)

[OUT]
    id  name         secondName chinese
0   1   Max Power   约翰·多伊    1
1   2   Jessica     Miller      0
2   3   约翰·多伊   哈拉尔       1
3   4   哈拉尔量杯   Johnny      0
4   5   Frank       High        0
```

What I want

```py
    id  name         secondName chinese
0   1   Max Power   约翰·多伊    1
1   2   Jessica     Miller      0
2   3   约翰·多伊   哈拉尔       1
3   4   哈拉尔量杯   Johnny      1
4   5   Frank       High        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `df['colName'].apply(lambda x: ...)` you can do `df.apply(lambda x, key: ..., args=('colName'), axis=1)`. Here, the key will be 'colName'.

In your case:

```
df['chinese'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: 1 if len(re.findall(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', x)) > 0 else 0)
df['chinese'] = df.apply(lambda x, key: 1 if x['chinese'] == 0 and len(re.findall(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', x[key])) > 0 else 0, args=('secondName',), axis=1) # changes are in this line
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But if I am run your code snippet I got the wrong output. It only recognized the first one.

Comment: And also `NameError: name 'kay' is not defined`